# Migrating to a new ERP and want to drop Vendor Accounts with no activity in 18 months

Tags: sql

I want a list of Vendors who have no recent activity.
Joining the Vendor Master to the Posted Invoice Payments history with an Left Outer Join.  The Where clause tests for Posted Invoice Less than 05/2020.  How do I make sure that there is no Posted Invoice activity after this cutoff date?  Should there be an AND condition with another test for NOT greater than 05/2020?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please understand that the people reading this question have no understanding of "vendors", "posted invoice payments" etc.  You will need to edit the question and post a [mcve] that shows the table definitions, sample data, and expected output.

Comment: try this logic : `select * from Vendor v
left join paymenthistory p on v.id=p.VendorId and p.invoicedate>='2020/05/01'
where p.id is null`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your tables are setup but something like the below should work:

```
SELECT * FROM VendorsTable a LEFT JOIN InvoiceHistoryTable b on a.ID = b.ID WHERE InvoiceDate > '2020-05-01'
```

You just replace my pretend table and field names with your actual ones.